# I recovered ETH on MetaMask sent to my ledger wallet via Binance Smart Chain

Tags: ether, ledger-nano-s, bsc

I sent ETH to my ledger hardware wallet using the Binance Smart Chain. As ledger does not support Binance Smart Chain I was able to recover the ETH on MetaMask. But the problem is that to send it back to Binance for example, I need BNB but ledger does not support it.

How can I finance or send the ETH back to Binance without BNB?

Thanks!

Comment: Send ether back to where ?

Comment: Just transfer some BNB to your ledger address by using metamask. Then use metamask to transfer your tokens.

Comment: hey, thanks - yes, that might work. Can the ETH address on my ledger (and MetaMask) accept BNB or is each address tied to one crypto? Thanks again!

Comment: You ledger address (linked with metamask) can accept BNB on BSC. I will write that as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer token on Binance Smart Chain, you must have a BNB balance on the address holding the tokens. BNB is the equivalent of ETH on Ethereum.

Simply transfer some BNB to your ledger address and you should be able to transfer the tokens (Eth or other tokens) on Binance Smart Chain by using metamask.

Make sure that you are using the correct network when transferring tokens (Ethereum vs Binance Smart Chain).